# Google Maps + plotting points (markers) based on zip code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know you can use google.maps.LatLng() to plot markers, but I don't know the lat and long. I know the zip code. Can I use it to plot markers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you can use the Geo Coding service to geocode the zip codes, you'll get a center point of the zip code which you can use for your marker:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: Be aware however that the geocoding service is subject to a quota and rate limit, if you need to plot lots of markers you may want to geocode them off-line.  This ["article" on geocoding strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) from the documentation is worth a read.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you! Ha, funny to have my article quoted back to me :-)